# Is there a way to express interface function polymorphism when the function will always receive the type it's defined on?

Tags: typescript, polymorphism, covariance

I was hoping to define an interface hierarchy, where the base interface declares a function, and each extension's version of that function receives its own type (rather than the base type). Minimally, I tried:

```js
interface IBase {
  a: string,
  f: (x: IBase) => any // Cause of the problem
}

interface IExtension extends IBase {
  b: string,
}

const f1 = (x: IExtension) => //... typechecks when using x.b

const ext1: IExtension = {
  a: "a1",
  b: "b1",
  f: f1 // This line doesn't typecheck because IExtension is not strictly IBase
}
```

The type error:

```js
Type '(x: IExtension) => {}[]' is not assignable to type '(x: IBase) => any'
```

Digging around, I saw [this answer regarding strictFunctionTypes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52115848/1492117). Making the following changes causes the program to typecheck, because methods aren't subject to `strictFunctionTypes`, and therefore allow bivariance:

```js
interface IBase {
  a: string,
  f(x: IBase): any
}
```

Edit: as explained in the [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75062033/is-there-a-way-to-express-interface-function-polymorphism-when-the-function-will#comment132462029_75062033) by [@jcalz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2887218/jcalz), this approach is blatantly unsound. It also doesn't capture the constraint that `f` is called with the type it's defined on.

Is there a way express this typing in TypeScript? Something like:

```js
interface IBase {
  a: string,
  f: (x: IBase | * extends IBase) => any
}
```

I haven't been able to find anything like that that avoids generics. I understand that generics could be used here, but I won't be walking that route, especially given the method syntax works as expected. Really appreciate any additional insight on this topic!

Comment: Because [it's provably unsound](https://tsplay.dev/NlLrxN).  A function that expects an input of `IExtension` cannot be safely passed an `IBase` that is not known to be an `IExtension`, but that's exactly what can happen if you try to define the types the way you're doing.  Does that makes sense?  If so I could write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: It seems you've got multiple questions here; you should probably edit to have just one primary question.  If you're asking how to correctly type this you could try using [polymorphic `this` types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/classes.html#this-types) as shown [here](https://tsplay.dev/wRzq5w).  But the question should be asking one thing.  Either "why is the compiler unhappy about this" or "is there a correct way to write this" but not both (or at least you shouldn't need both answered to accept the answer)  Let me know which one is primary.

Comment: I see the problem, for sure. The way the rest of the program is structured makes doing that impossible—`f` is only ever called with the type it is defined on/with (i.e. IExtension's `f` will always receive an `IExtension`, etc.), but I want to reuse certain `f`s and maintain their specificity. Does that make sense? I was hoping to keep things limited to basic interfaces and avoid generics, classes, etc., but I don't think that will be doable, so I'll just restructure things. Your example helped a lot for where I was losing the thread.

Comment: Doing what is impossible? I don’t see (explicit) generics or classes in my suggestion to use polymorphic `this`.

Comment: And so would an answer showing the unsoundness suffice here? If so I’ll write it up

Comment: Ah, yes, polymorphic `this` might be a direction that makes sense. My response to your first comment was being typed before I saw your second comment. Polymorphic `this` is really what I was hoping to find from this, thank you! I think the questions go hand in hand: "the way I hoped to express this is clearly unacceptable; why, and is there something I'm missing that could help?" I will review the question to see if I can't unify the question more elegantly.

Comment: You have answered both! I'd be happy to accept a write up that summarizes the info you've provided here.

Comment: I have tried to clarify the question around getting to polymorphic `this` Type as the answer. That is exactly what I was looking for, but it is in the Classes section of the documentation and hadn't come up in my search.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you want to use the [polymorphic `this` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/classes.html#this-types), which is sort of an implicit [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) type referring to the current type:

```
interface IBase {
  a: string,
  f: (x: this) => any
  //     ^^^^
}
```

Then when you extend `IBase`, the `f` method of the extensions will automatically refer to the extensions and not `IBase`:

```
interface IExtension extends IBase {
  b: string,
}

type IXF = IExtension['f'];
// type IXF = (x: IExtension) => any

const ext1: IExtension = {
  a: "a1",
  b: "b1",
  f: x => x.b.toUpperCase()
}
```

and

```
interface ISomethingElse extends IBase {
  z: number
}

type ISF = ISomethingElse['f']
// type ISF = (x: ISomethingElse) => any

const sth2: ISomethingElse = {
  a: "a2",
  f: s => s.z.toFixed(),
  z: 123
}
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=99&ts=4.9.4#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJICE4GcUG8CwAUMsnAFzJZhSgDmANESTBQBQAeFYAFsFgJTIAvAD5SIAJ5NkAehkkFAPWWKiAXyJFQkWIhSoAou0ggswAPYhkEYxBAATLGkw5kBYsgBGFKjRAN1IjAJAAd9AA0AMWE0IxMzSwBtAHIYZIBdAG4iOWRgsLQomI4KQ1tTCxBBUXEpQi1waHgkNABlcwBbCB46AwAbVxsTR2dsPGkALwoQAFcOz2hAwnz9VuihNs7u3n9+nBS09Jz5Fbb15BLNrp7dgYhqsThJTXrXhEsqa2MARlK4uwSVg27hI5GQACI4N9wYwPN4IZ5obDmBR2MIxOwAHSeTFgcwAVRCYSgAGExqx+EsiO9TGBKDwAEyldrXHa0PYoYHSMGQhkw6QsSjoyiYia48yRYDsCD2CnI5BTZDfBkAZiphCAA)